# get Geo Coordinate in vue js

Tags: vue.js, geolocation, lex, vuex

I want client current geolocation, for accuracy, i put 10000 timeout

```
 var options = {
      timeout: 10000
    };
```

This is js function

```
function getCoordinates() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (
      !("geolocation" in navigator) ||
      !("getCurrentPosition" in navigator.geolocation)
    ) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error("geolocation API not available"));
    }
    var options = {
      timeout: 10000
    };

    // browser prompts for permission
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      getPositionCallBack,
      reject,
      options
    );

    function getPositionCallBack(position) {
      var coords = "";
      try {
        coords = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          long: position.coords.longitude
        };
      } catch (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(coords);
    }
  });
}
```

Store:

```
var Ui = new WebUi({
coordincates:'',//initialise
});

export default {
  name: "app",
  store: Ui.store,
  components: { Page },
  data() {
    return {
      favIcon: getFavIcon()
    };
  }
};
```

updates WebUi coordinate after Promise completed.

I am updating store again after get coordinate then getting following error in vue js.

```
Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

I did modified store/index.js
updates

```
strict: false,
```

**now issue is how do i update my coordinate of store from javascript.**

Comment: Show your store declaration. Show the point where you are trying to update it.

Comment: HI @acdcjunior I updated question,

Comment: What is `WebUi` in `var Ui = new WebUi({`?

Comment: This is library like vuex

Comment: Can you point a link to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you set `scrict` to `false`, you will be able to mutate the store's state from any component like below:

```js
// use this code inside a component (only throws no warning if strict: false)
this.$store.state.coordinates = {x: 1, y: 2};
```

Notice the name is `coordinates`, in you example your store was `coordincates`, I'm assuming this was a typo.

If `coordinates`  doesn't exist in the store, use:

```js
// use this code inside a component (only throws no warning if strict: false)
// Use Vue.set() when the property may not exist inside the store yet
Vue.set(this.$store.state, 'coordinates', {x: 1, y: 2});
```

That being said, *the best* would be to leave `strict` to `true` and create [**mutations**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html). Since you are using `WebUi`, it may have specific ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks of your answer but, how do i update store from javascript?

Comment: I did import store, this.$store give undefined

Comment: The `this.$store.state.coordinates = {x: 1, y: 2};` part.

Comment: I used store.state.sessionAttributes.coordinates=JSON.stringify(coords);

Comment: console.log gives actual value 
console.log(store.state.sessionAttributes.coordinates);
but actually its not update actual store

Comment: Without knowing better, I'd say, use `Vue.set(store.state, 'lex', store.state.lex); Vue.set(store.state.lex.sessionAttributes, 'coordinates', JSON.stringify(coords));`

Comment: gives TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '{"lat":null,"long":null}' in et

Comment: LexApp.vue?ec76:116 error:  TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '{"lat":18.5358566,"long":73.8613063}' in 
    at Function.set (webpack-internal:///4:1026:11)
    at loadLexWebUi (webpack-internal:///167:116:48)
I used JSON.stringify to get string yet give above errro

Comment: at that line
 Vue.set(store.state.lex.sessionAttributes.coordinates, JSON.stringify(coords));

Comment: That's wrong. The correct is `Vue.set(store.state.lex.sessionAttributes, 'coordinates', JSON.stringify(coords));`. Notice the second argument is `'coordinates'` and the first ends with `sessionAttributes`.

Comment: Thanks its working now , but its not certain, some time update and some time goes blank, but in console each time shows correct value, can we fixed it for permanent basis

Comment: Use this sequence of 3 commands to update: `Vue.set(store.state, 'lex', store.state.lex);
Vue.set(store.state.lex, 'sessionAttributes', store.state.lex.sessionAttributes);
Vue.set(store.state.lex.sessionAttributes, 'coordinates', JSON.stringify(coords));`

Comment: Its working but not always, so i modified code create component for that, and used location.storage, now i am validating is not empty if yes then check location.storage and get value from there

Comment: Alright. For more consistent behavior, use `Vue.set` when handling those `lex` and other properties. That's it. Cheers.

Comment: Anytime ! ! : )